# d3-tip npm module not working with browserify

Tags: d3.js, browserify

First I installed d3-tip with `npm install d3-tip` v0.6.7 then browserify'd my project without any issues.

My js looks like the following

```
var d3 = require("d3");
var d3tip = require("d3-tip");

    var tip = d3tip()
              .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
              .offset([-10, 0])
              .html(function(d) {
                return "<strong>Hello World:</strong>";
              });
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: d3 is undefined in my bundle.js yet
```

I'm using d3 elsewhere in my code without issue which makes me believe the error is in the npm module for d3 tip but I could be wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found your question and it was the exact same problem I had, after trying a lot of things I found that you can pass arguments to `require`.

I solved my problem using:

```
var d3 = require("d3");
var d3tip = require('d3-tip')(d3);
```

And then you can call d3tip as you already have.