# Using d3-tip with npm: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, npm

I've installed `d3": "^3.5.17"` and `"d3-tip": "^0.7.1"` using npm ([d3-tip documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3-tip)). Then in my `index.js` file I have this code:

```
var d3 = require('d3');
var d3tip = require('d3-tip')(d3);
console.log('d3 version', d3.version);
var tip = d3tip().attr('class', 'd3-tip').html(function(d) { return "hello world"; })
```

But when I build the index file with browserify and load it in the browser, I see an error from the `var tip` line:

```
index.js:247 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
```

This is coming from this function in the d3-tip source code:

```
function getSVGNode(el) {
  el = el.node()
  if(el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'svg')
    return el
  return el.ownerSVGElement
}
```

It looks like this function is expecting a node to be passed to it? But where would this come from?

The build itself does not throw any errors, and I think I'm requiring d3-tip correctly, [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35067167/d3-tip-npm-module-not-working-with-browserify). The console statement shows d3 version 3.5.17, as expected.

UPDATE: Here's my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "watchify index.js -o main.js --debug --verbose",
    "build": "browserify index.js | uglifyjs > main.min.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "^3.5.17",
    "d3-tip": "^0.7.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.12",
    "datatables.net-bs": "^1.10.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.10",
    "watchify": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

And I installed the files with `npm install`.

Comment: This seems correct, but, could you post your `.on('mouseover')` code?

Comment: It could be that youre directly passing a value in the `.html()` function instead of a function, so that `d3-tip` is trying to pass this value on to a node on initialization, which it doesnt have. Try using `.html(function(d) {
                return "hello world";
              });`

Comment: @Craicerjack makes no difference, I'm afraid. have updated with that.

Comment: @davcs86 I've cut the whole file down so it's just the four lines above, still throwing the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was happening because I was trying to use the latest version of d3-tip (which requires v4 of D3) with v3 of D3.

Reverting to older versions of both fixed things:

```
"d3": "^3.5.17",
"d3-tip": "^0.6.7"
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this.

Comment: I am using   "d3": "^4.13.0", and "d3-tip": "^0.7.1". It's still giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
var tip = d3tip().attr('class', 'd3-tip').html(function(d) { return "hello world"; })
```

must be

```
var tip = d3.tip().attr('class', 'd3-tip').html(function(d) { return "hello world"; })
```

You can check my implementation @:

[Source](https://github.com/davcs86/d3-polytree-graph/blob/master/lib/SimpleNetwork.js#L333) (Lines: 17, 91, 333-339, 685-692)

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davcs86/yywby23u/3/)

Comment: Thanks, OK, now I'm really confused :) I can see it's working for you, but the exactly equivalent code still throws the same error for me! Might nuke `package.json` and `node_modules` and start again from scratch...

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your line:

```
var d3tip = require('d3-tip')(d3);
```

You should not be calling d3.tip(foo) with the d3 reference itself, but with a d3 *selection* (which it can then invoke `.node()` on).

I think this should probably be:

```
d3.tip = require('d3-tip');
```